# Vue.js Global Axios Calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, minix

I am writing a project which uses so many Axios calls from different pages. Instead of using Axios calls multiple times, is it possible to write a single Axios call function and use it in each pages.

For ex, define an "axiosCall" function once and than use it in different pages by just calling that function.

```
axiosCall (serviceName, parameter) {
  axios
    .get(`http://localhost/xApi/` + serviceName + `/` + parameter)
    .then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.exceptionHandler('Error at get ' + serviceName + ' : ', e)
    })
}
```

Then use it like

```
var userData = axiosCall('user',1)
var roleData = axiosCall('role',2)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Definitely possible. What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Indeed it is possible. Yet as far as I know, the best practice for this should be that you create service classes for each service, and include the axios calls (CRUD) for each service inside them. Then it would be like var userData = userService.getUserById(5); etc.

Comment: I read about mixin, extending and inheritance in javascript. But actually I am new at JavaScript and so I could not analyse which is the best practice. So I am looking for a way to figure it out.

Comment: Look into Vuex for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

In your bootstrap file i.e `main.js` you could do `Vue.prototype.$axiosCall = function () { ... }` before you initialise Vue then within your components you could just call `this.$axiosCall('user', 1)`.

Another way would be to use a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) (axiosMixin.js):

```
export default {
  methods: {
    axiosCall () { ... }
  }
}
```

Then include it as a global mixin in your bootstrap file like: `Vue.mixin(UserMixin)` (again, in your bootstrap file before the initialise has been done).

Comment: Using mixin solved my problem in an efficient way. Thank you webnoob.

Comment: Glad it helped and not a problem.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe not the best solution, but it can work

axios-conf.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'CUSTOM_HEADER': 'SOME TEXT',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

window.axios.axiosCall = function(serviceName, parameter) {
  axios.get(`http://localhost/xApi/` + serviceName + `/` + parameter)
    .then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.exceptionHandler('Error at get ' + serviceName + ' : ', e)
    })
}
```

Comment: You're right, it's not the best solution and should be avoided.